# How can I retrieve the last location in android when GPS/Mobile Data /Wifi is off

Tags: android, location, maps, provider

is android stores last location, if so is it possible to get the last location when GPS/Mobile Data/Wifi is off.

Comment: fusedlocation api

Comment: check this Link for reference:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Answer (score 0):

The last known location of the device provides a handy base from which to start, ensuring that the app has a known location before starting the periodic location updates.

check this link .its very useful to us.

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html

Comment: this solution not working properly, it gives null all the time

Answer (score 0):

You could use locationmanager

```
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);//get bese location provider

    if (provider != null && !provider.equals(""))
    {

       //check for permission
                if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Get the location from the given provider
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {

               String Latitude = "" + location.getLatitude();
                String Longitude = "" + location.getLongitude();
            }

        }
 }
```

You need permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```